# Download xml file from site to android, wrong encode

Tags: android, encoding

On remote http server, I create test.xml file in Sublime text2, and save it with encoding utf-8.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Utf-8' ?>
<Shops>
 <Shop name="one"></Shop>
 <Shop name="two" ></Shop>
 <Shop name="three"></Shop>
</Shops>
```

Then I download it on my device:

```
String str="";
            URL url = new URL(Server+urls);
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }
            str = new String(baf.toByteArray(),"Utf-8");
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            out = new DataOutputStream(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            out.writeUTF(str);
            out.close();
```

After it, through DDMS file explorer I download it on my macbook, open in Sublime text2, and saw:

```
008e 3c3f 786d 6c20 7665 7273 696f 6e3d
2731 2e30 2720 656e 636f 6469 6e67 3d27
5574 662d 3827 203f 3e0d 0a3c 5368 6f70
733e 0d0a 203c 5368 6f70 206e 616d 653d
226f 6e65 223e 3c2f 5368 6f70 3e0d 0a20
3c53 686f 7020 6e61 6d65 3d22 7477 6f22
203e 3c2f 5368 6f70 3e0d 0a20 3c53 686f
7020 6e61 6d65 3d22 7468 7265 6522 3e3c
2f53 686f 703e 0d0a 3c2f 5368 6f70 733e
```

Then I chose reopen with encoding utf-8, and saw (By the way, I can't copy/past what I saw):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.writeUTF` uses [modified UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29), not UTF-8.

The `0x00 0x8e` is big endian unsigned short for the length of the XML, which is 142 and matches the real length which is 142 as well.

Use this:

```
str = new String(baf.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
    openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
    Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()
);
osw.write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you're converting from/to bytes, but this problem may be a good candidate for [StAX](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/20/introduction-to-stax.html#reading-xml).

Checkout the reading and writing sections.